# Equivalence Statement with three arrays

Tags: fortran

So i have a homework question:

Suppose we have three arrays dimensioned, A(1000), B(700), and C (200). Further suppose that A is never in use
at the same time as B or C, but that B and C may be in use at the same time. Write a FORTRAN EQUIVALENCE
statement to share as much storage as much as possible.

Now i know nothing at all about writing a FORTRAN EQUIVALENCE statement but i looked it up on google and studied it a little. I got this as the answer:

```
EQUIVALENCE(B, C) or EQUIVALENCE((A), (B(1),C(1)))
```

Can anyone help me out on this? How would i go about solving this problem?

Comment: What is it that you think `equivalence(b,c)` means?  (That is, how many aspects need we address?)

Comment: @francescalus I think it means all addresses of `b` are shared with `c`

Comment: So if `b` and `c` have memory in common that means we can't independently assign to one just one of those variables.  I'd read the question as asking the opposite: we want to be able to use a block of memory either for `a` or for both `b` and `c` (but these latter without them overlapping).  Is that how you also take the question?

Comment: On, and there is an important bit of information missing: what are the types of the various variables?

Comment: @francescalus I take the answer to questions as "We want A to be completely independent from B and C but for B and C they can be independent or shared." Also that is the full question that was given to me. No mention of the types of the various variables

Comment: `EQUIVALENCE` in homework? Please tell me you're joking. Chapman marks `EQUIVALENCE` with the unambiguous **DANGER -- DO NOT USE** tag.

Comment: @chw21 I agree with you to a degree.  But long after I retire there will still be a lot of code in use with lots of `equivalence` (and worse) that people will still need to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going further, I'll say that I think it's good to have an understanding/appreciation of `equivalence` but that rarely will this be the correct tool to address a modern computing problem.

My answer here isn't to tell you the correct statement to use.  That's partly because of it being homework, but mainly because there is insufficient information to give a complete answer.  More on that later.

I interpret the question differently from how you do.

> suppose that A is never in use at the same time as B or C

Back when `equivalence` was the right thing to do memory was expensive or limited.  If we knew that two very large arrays were required, but were never required to be used at the same time, we'd use the same parts of memory to store both variables: at some points in the code we'd be using it as, say, `x`, and at some points part of it would be `idx`.  This is one use of `equivalence` and the one for this question.

Saying that `A` is never in use at the same time as `B` and `C`, but that `B` and `C` may be in use at the same time means we can use the same lump of memory for `A` at some points in the code and later on have `B` and `C` in part, but *distinct parts for each*, of that memory used by `A` earlier.

```
equivalence (b,c)
```

then, is saying the wrong thing.  This says that the start of `B` is in the same memory location as the start of `C`.  So if we change `b(1)` we also change the value of `c(1)`.

You should be looking at something like

```
equivalence (a(1), b(1)) (a(n), c(1))
```

where `a(n)` refers to a storage unit after the end of `b`'s storage.

Now, what this n should be, and indeed if there even is one, will depend on the sizes of the various elements of the variables.  This we don't know.

Perhaps we could use implicit typing (after all, there's `equivalence`) to say they are all default reals and each element is the same length, in which case you can give an answer.

Comment: But more importantly: **DO NOT USE EQUIVALENCE** any more. (Except maybe, *maybe*, if you really know what you're doing)

Comment: [Or, :(, you're stuck with a compiler/boss/prof which doesn't understand `associate` or `target`.]